# Ajax filter in django not showing in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm not sure if my Ajax implementation is right. Using Django built in tags, the objects I am passing using Ajax is not showing up on my template HTML page.

**view_results.html**

```
<div>
   <input id="search" name="search" type="text" class="query-search form-control input-sm" style="width:350px;" placeholder="Search trail name...">
</div>
<div class="overflow">
   <div class="list-group">
      {% if results|length %}
        {% for r in results %}
           <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>{{ r.trail_id }}</strong> <br> {{ r.trail_long }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
          Not found
      {% endif %}
   </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $('#search').keyup(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/search/get_trail/",
            data: {
                'search_text' : $('#search').val()
            },
            success: function(data){console.log(data)},
            dataType: 'html'
        });
    });
  });
```

**views.py**

```
def trails_view(request):
   trails = Trail.objects.all()
   trails_json = serialize('geojson' , trails, fields=('trails_type', 'trails_id', 'wkb_geometry',))
   trails_geojson = json.loads(trails_json)
   trails_geojson.pop('crs', None)
   trails_geojson = json.dumps(trails_geojson)

   return render(request, '/view_trails.html', {'trails':trails,
                                             'trails_geojson':trails_geojson})

def get_trails(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        search_text = request.GET['search_text']
        if search_text is not None and search_text != u"":
            search_text = request.GET['search_text']
            results = Trail.objects.filter(trails_id__contains=search_text)
        else:
            results = []

        return render(request, '/view_trails.html', {'results': results})
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^view/', views.trails_view, name='trails_view'),
url(r'^search/get_trails/', views.get_trails, name='get_trails'),
```

I am wondering if `trails_view` and `get_trails` is the reason of the function not showing up the results upon ajax call. I tried printing out the contents of `results` in `views.py` and it does filter out according to the `search_text`. The problem is the contents not showing up in the template tags.

I wanted to do something like this: [Simple Ajax Search](http://simpleajaxsearch.herokuapp.com/)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not doing anything in your Ajax success method to actually show the results.

Comment: @DanielRoseman but shouldn't the objects be automatically passed to the template upon rendering it?

Comment: Yes, they are. But what happens with the rendered template? It gets passed to your Ajax success, but you ignore it.

Comment: @Reiion templates are rendered server-side, javascript is executed browser-side, so just making an ajax call from the browser will not automagically update the _already rendered_ html code in the browser. That's what the `success` callback is: to let you update the DOM with what the ajax call sent back.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Oh I see thanks for that explanation. I can commonly see examples of `success` callback updating html elements. Then I guess my question is how can I get the response and put it to use in the tags `{% for r in results %}` or I can't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates are rendered server-side, javascript is executed browser-side, so just making an ajax call from the browser will not automagically update the already rendered html code in the browser. That's what the success callback is: to let you update the DOM with what the ajax call sent back.

You ask:

> Then I guess my question is how can I get the response and put it to use in the tags {% for r in results %} or I can't

The short answer is "you can't".

Re-read the above: when the ajax call is made, the original template has been rendered to plain html and this html has been sent as the response body to the browser, so there's no more template nor templatetags here. All you have at this point are the http response's body and the current's page DOM.

Now the view serving your ajax call can still returns html generated by a template (which seems to be the case with your current code), so you can easily build a dom object from the response's body html, extract the relevant node(s) from this dom and replace some of the current page's dom  with these nodes.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I was also able to resolve it : `success: function(data){
                    var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('#list-group').html();
                    $('#list-group').html(result);
                }`

Comment: I will clean up those tags since it's not needed as you have explained :)

Comment: I never said the templatetags were not needed - you need them to generate the html returned to the ajax call. I strongly suggest you take some time understanding how the http protocol works...

Comment: actually yes, I just did last night and finally understood it better. It's working great now! I was in a rush and new to Django and Python that I just dived in right through. Again, thank you for the direction!